# How to load app from android studio to my phone?

Tags: android-studio

When I launch the app again after loading it from android studio and closing it once, a white screen is  shown. The app is not launched when I start it for the second time.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what you are trying to say but you can use the run option in Android Studio to select your target device also what you can do is you can export it as an APK from the android studio and run it directly on your device(not preferred for testing your application though)

Comment: Apologies. I mean how can I stop the application after it is loaded on my phone? When I close the app and restart it, I get a white screen on my app

Comment: there is a red square button in Android Studio to terminate the running application.